# Nginx Access Log Name Based on Non-WWW Host

Tags: regex, variables, nginx, logging

So,

I've got a server with around 30 virtual host configurations, each in their own separate file. My main aim at this point is to name the access log based on the `$host` variable.

At the moment, I'm using the following, inside of my HTTP block to be applied to all conf files:

```
http {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/$host.access.log
}
```

I'd like to be able to rewrite the above `$host` **without** the *www.*, and just keep the domain itself. I've found the following solution for that:

```
    if ($domain ~* www\.(.*)) {                                                                                                                                                                              
            set $domain $1;                                                                                                                                                                                  
            rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$domain$1 permanent;                                                                                                                                                       
    }
```

Only problem is.. 'IF' Directives are not allowed inside of the 'http' block.. Is there anyway I can achieve this, whilst still being within the 'http' block? Maybe using 'map'?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: put the `access_log` setting in each of the virtual server configuration file, within the `server` directive.

Comment: The sole purpose of this question is to find out if it's possible to do it in the http block..

Comment: Suit yourself. You don't define the `server_name` or `root` of each virtual host at `http` anyway. So why it must be in `http` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a map

```
http {
   map $host $hostw {
        default         $host;
        ~*^www\.(.*)     $1;
   }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/$hostw.access.log
}
```